# Android app error: INSTALL_FAILURE_OLDER_SDK with an updated phone O.o

Tags: java, android

im trying to create my first android app and im experiencing a problem, i tried searching and i know it has something to do with minSdkVersion/targetSdkVersion, the weird thing is that i have set minSdkVersion to 8 and targetSdkVersion to 19 a.k.a KitKat, my phone runs KitKat 4.4.2 so its sdk version is not older :L i am seriously as every thread i read through just says that the phone has a to low/old sdk version and that can't be the problem with mine :P

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.test.app">

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".Rate"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

settings.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 'android-L'
buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.test.app"
    minSdkVersion 8
    targetSdkVersion 19
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        runProguard false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

Comment: Try changing `compileSdkVersion 'android-L'` to `compileSdkVersion 19`.